# NullPointerException occurs though the class is available

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, ant, intellij-idea

I have created a project with ant build and I use intellij idea 13 as IDE.
This project is a j2EE, hibernate project the war file is created and deployed automatically on the jetty server. I use java service wrapper also. I have attached [image: a snapshot] how src looks like and [image: how the target directory looks like]. There you can see some classes are missing on target.

This is the build file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<target name="clean.project">
    <delete dir="target/*"/>
</target>

<target name="build.war" description="Create Web archive" depends="compile">

    <fileset dir="src/main/webapp">
        <include name="**/*"/>
    </fileset>

    <war destfile="target/${web.archive.name}" webxml="${web.app.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <classes dir="target/classes"/>
        <lib dir="lib">
            <exclude name="standalone.jar"/>
        </lib>
    </war>

</target>

<target name="build.standalone.app" depends="compile">
    <jar basedir="target/classes" destfile="lib/standalone.jar">

    </jar>
</target>

<path id="dev.lib">
    <fileset dir="lib">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="lib">
        <include name="**/*.war"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="compile" depends="clean.project">
    <mkdir dir="target/classes"/>
    <javac srcdir="src/main/java" destdir="target/classes">
        <classpath refid="dev.lib"/>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="build.stand-alone" description="Build a stand alone application"
        depends="build.standalone.app, build.war">
    <mkdir dir="${stand-alone.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${stand-alone.dir}/bin"/>
    <mkdir dir="${stand-alone.dir}/lib"/>

    <copy todir="${stand-alone.dir}/bin">
        <fileset dir="src/main/bin"/>
    </copy>

    <copy todir="${stand-alone.dir}/lib">
        <fileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar">
            <exclude name="gson-1.7.2.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="lib/jetty" includes="*.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="target" includes="*.war"/>
    </copy>

</target>
```

1. Can someone tell me why that is.

Also, I have created an object of SmsHandler inside the SampleClient but It gives me a NullPointerException always.

```
private MtSmsReq createSimpleMtSms(MoSmsReq moSmsReq) {
    SmsHandler smsHandler;
    try {
        smsHandler = new SmsHandler(moSmsReq.getSourceAddress(), moSmsReq.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        MtSmsReq mtSmsReq = new MtSmsReq();
        mtSmsReq.setMessage(e.getMessage());
        List<String> addressList;
        addressList = new ArrayList<String>();
        addressList.add(moSmsReq.getSourceAddress());
        mtSmsReq.setDestinationAddresses(addressList);
        return mtSmsReq;
    }

    MtSmsReq mtSmsReq = new MtSmsReq();
    List<String> addressList;
    addressList = new ArrayList<String>();
    mtSmsReq.setMessage("Exception NOT occurred");
    addressList.add(moSmsReq.getSourceAddress());
    mtSmsReq.setDestinationAddresses(addressList);
    return mtSmsReq;
}
```

2.please help me to find why that exception comes.

3 And Idea IDE shows the main and java directories are packages (see the screen shot). How can I get rid of that.

Here the stacktrace.

```
INFO: Unexpected error occurred
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at main.java.hms.kite.samples.client.SmsHandler.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at hms.kite.samples.client.SimpleClient.createSimpleMtSms(Unknown Source
)
        at hms.kite.samples.client.SimpleClient.onReceivedSms(Unknown Source)
        at hms.kite.samples.api.sms.MoSmsReceiver$2.run(MoSmsReceiver.java:118)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please show the exception stacktrace...

Comment: You posted everything but the thing that would actually help us answer your question.

Comment: If the exception is inside the try block, obviously its because the parameter being passed into the function is null. There's only one line in the try, so `moSmsReq.` must be the offender.